# Create multidimensional array from standard array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Most likely I'm doing this wayyyyyy too complicated. But I'm in the need of converting multiple arrays to multidimensional array key's. So arrays like this:

```
Array //$original
(
    [0] => 500034
    [1] => 500035 //these values need to become 
                  //consecutive keys, in order of array
)
```

Needs to become:

```
Array
(
    [50034][50035] => array()
)
```

This needs to be done recursively, as it might also require that it becomes deeper:

```
Array
(
    [50034][50036][50126] => array() //notice that the numbers 
                    //aren't necessarily consecutive, though they are 
                    //in the order of the original array
)
```

My current code:

```
$new_array = array();

foreach($original as $k => $v){ //$original from first code

    if((gettype($v) === 'string' || gettype($v) === 'integer') 
    && !array_key_exists($v, $original)){ //check so as to not have illigal offset types

        $new_array =& $original[array_search($v, $original)];

        echo 'In loop: <br />';
        var_dump($new_array);
        echo '<br />';
    }
}

echo "After loop <br />";
var_dump($new_array);
echo "</pre><br />";
```

Gives me:

```
In loop: 
int(500032)

In loop: 
int(500033)

After loop 
int(500033)
```

Using this code `$new_array =& $original[array_search($v, $original)];` I expected After loop: `$new_array[50034][50035] => array()`.

What am I doing wrong? Been at this for hours on end now :(

**EDIT** to answer "why" I'm trying to do this
I'm reconstructing facebook data out of a database. Below is my own personal data that isn't reconstructing properly, which is why I need the above question answered.

```
[500226] => Array
    (
        [own_id] => 
        [entity] => Work
        [name] => Office Products Depot
        [500227] => Array
            (
                [own_id] => 500226
                [entity] => Employer
                [id] => 635872699779885
            )

        [id] => 646422765379085
    )

[500227] => Array
    (
        [500228] => Array
            (
                [own_id] => 500227
                [entity] => Position
                [id] => 140103209354647
            )

        [name] => Junior Programmer
    )
```

As you can see, the ID `[500227]` is a child of `[500226]`, however, because I haven't got the path to the child array, a new array is created. The current parentage only works to the first level.

`[own_id]` is a key where the value indicates which other key should be its parent. Which is why the first array (`[500226]`) doesn't have a value for `[own_id]`.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?!

Comment: To reconstruct fragmented database data, but the question isn't why, it's how ;) But I'll put in an edit to show what I'm trying to do. Give me a few mins ;)

Comment: The question usually is why behind the scenes, hidden in a "how" ala-[XY problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). :)

Comment: Fair point @Mike, I've added the "why" to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something recursively, do it recursively. I hope that's what you meant to do.

```
public function pivotArray($array, $newArray)
    {
        $shifted = array_shift($array);
        if( $shifted !== null )
        {
            return $this->pivotArray($array, array($shifted=>$newArray));
        }
        return $newArray;
    }

$array = array(432, 432532, 564364);
$newArray = $this->pivotArray($array, array());
```

**Edit: After the question's edit it doesn't seem to be very relevant. Well, maybe someone will find it useful anyway.**